# Why is fire sticky?

Tags: everyday-life, combustion, adhesion

I've always wondered why it is possible to pick things up with a burning ember if those things also catch fire.

The simplest example I know of, or perhaps just common, is the "cherry" falling off a cigarette. It is relatively easy to reconnect the ember to the main shaft, often by simply bringing them in contact. Even upside-down against gravity.

Somewhat obviously the ember is 'chasing' the nearest, best fuel source. What causes the force holding the two objects together? I naively assume electromagnetism at some level is at play but if so, please elaborate. If not, why is it sticky?

> **Edit: ** As per request, I've [uploaded a video demonstration](https://youtu.be/st3ShzwB_xs). Admittedly not the best demo of this effect but it shows the general idea. Test any ember-to-ember connections, (for instance firework "punk" sticks) and the ease of adherence is readily noticeable compared to unlit material. https://youtu.be/st3ShzwB_xs

Comment: I haven't experienced this, do you have a video or something demonstrating the phenomenon?

Comment: One really needs a demonstration. The general answer will be convection: the air is heated and lifts, pressure between fire point and object lower than atmosheric, force inward, simulates attraction.

Comment: Added a demo video for clarification. Quality is fairly poor but hopefully enough.

Comment: I went outside just now and tried burning tissue paper and seeing if it would stick together, and it doesn't, so my conclusion is that fire isn't sticky.

Comment: I tried with matches. Flames do not attract each other, so it is not fire that is sticky. Of course flames generate different air currents than two cigaret stubs.  I will keep the question in mind when winter starts  and I will have embers to experiment with. (unless someone gives a good answer. I still think it is underpressure somehow)

Comment: I've not observed this before.  Could it be that the shredded tobacco acts somewhat like Velcro?  The "cherry" at the tip of a cigarette must have some unburned tobacco or it would not still be on fire.

Comment: @anna I was able to get the same effect with matches but it was pretty tricky. It's just conjecture from the tactile sensation but I think the loose, dry, easily catching tobacco leaves enhance the effect. When I used a match I had to push the lit match lightly into a smoldering one. About three tries and it picked up -- I'll try to make a second video with matches.

Comment: @LewisMiller the effect does appear partly dependent on material being used as fuel. However the shredded tobacco by itself does not adhere very well. Similarly I could not get fully burnt or unburnt matches to "stick", only when the wood was already hot enough for the ember to 'spread' would it stay attached.